# XAML listviewitem behavior of a button if mousover

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm working on a UWP for Windows 10 and wrote the following XAML Code:

```
<ListView  x:Name="listTimetypes"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Width="220"  Margin="8">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button x:Name="btnTimeTypes" Content="{Binding Name}" Width="200" Margin="4" 
                                            Foreground="Black" Background="#FFE6E6E6" 
                                            Style="{StaticResource HoverButtonStyleChange}"
                                            FontSize="15"  Click="btnTimeTypes_Click"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

So here comes my question how can i make the items of the listview behave like a button if the mouse hovers a item?

looking forword to hear anwsers

Comment: a ListView is already animated when you're hovering over it, so change the ListViewItem style. Now you're setting the item (which is a button) fixed to the hover style of the button.

Comment: Thank you for your help i solved the Problem now :)